# Notepad++ opens obsolete version of file

Tags: notepad++

I have a file edited with standard notepad of WIN 8.1, when i open this file with notepad++ my changes aren't visible. When i open the file with any other program the changes are visible.

I've tried to reload the file with the reload button but my changes aren't visible.

Is there a cache in notepad++?

**UPDATE 1**

I've tried to disable "settings -> preferences -> backup -> Remember current session next launch" and it still loads the wrong file.

Comment: Is the file a configuration file for Notepad++ or one of its plugins? Notepad++ writes new versions of many of its configuration files just before it exits. The help pages on the Notepad++ wiki describe this behaviour and how to deal with it.

Comment: No it's a .xml which i created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to disable: Remember current session option.

settings -> preferences -> backup -> Remember current session next launch

from wiki [Wiki link](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Configuration_Files):

```
When it looks like a setting is lost, a common cause is that there are 
two sets of files, one in the %APPDATA%\Notepad++ folder and one 
alongside Notepad++.exe. Then either N++ doesn't read the right file, or 
the setting was saved into the wrong file.
```

There probably is some copy of the file that u are trying to open, you have to delete it in order to get the right one. When u change name of the file u are trying to open, Note++ is still opening it as the wrong one?

Comment: I've deleted it notepad has recognized that file is deleted, then i restored the file and now it works.